# Bezier curve path in 3D: how to take into account linear speed, linear acceleration and angular speed?

Tags: 3d, geometry, game-physics

We have a ship running in space, going from a point A with a velocity vector V<sub>a</sub> to a point B with velocity vector V<sub>b</sub>. We calculate the point for the Bezier curve as:

P<sub>0</sub> = A
P<sub>1</sub> = A + ( V<sub>a</sub> * k )
P<sub>2</sub> = B - ( V<sub>b</sub> * k )
P<sub>3</sub> = B

We still have to find the "correct" value for k, but it's not important now ( Anyway we found that a good value could be  (4 * (sqrt(2) - 1) / 3) from [here](http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/)).

Until that, it's easy: we calculate points with the parametric formula, and everyting works fine. What we really like is that the ship "slows down" when doing a curve, and it's realistic.

Now, we want to differentiate ships letting them have a maximum linear speed (V<sub>max</sub>), a maximum linear acceleration (a<sub>max</sub>, absolute value for acceleration and deceleration) and a maximum angular speed (ω<sub>max</sub>, where curvature radius R = V/ω). This brings in many problems:

a) The curve could be "wrong", as it could have curves that are too sharp to do with ω<sub>max</sub>, or not having enough space to decelerate with a<sub>max</sub> being too small or V<sub>a</sub> being too much.

This should be fixed choosing P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> "wisely", putting into account in some way ω<sub>max</sub> and a<sub>max</sub>. I "guess" it could be something directly proportional to V<sub>a</sub> and inversely proportional to ω<sub>max</sub> and a<sub>max</sub>, but here my math and geometry skills are not enough.

b) Here I could be wrong, but it seems that in 3D the curve never gets spikes, and that's good™. The problem is that if the two vectors (P<sub>1</sub> - P<sub>0</sub>) and (P<sub>2</sub> + P<sub>3</sub>) are on the same plane, spikes can come out, and I would add a "displacement" over the normal dimension (normal to the plane) so I can avoid spikes. But I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: A) is called "motion planning", and it is not trivial. B) is unclear-- "spikes"? The two *vectors* will always be in a plane; do you mean that the points {P0, P1, P2, P3} are coplanar?

Comment: @Beta: for B), the two vector A and B (and thus, the 4 points) MAY be coplanar, but it's just a special case. Usually they aren't.

Comment: you sure it has much to with the vectors being on the same plane? the interpolation on each axis is independent of the other. the spikes usually come out when the points P1,P2 are "silly" in relation to P0,P2. if i remember correctly there's a relatively simply prove that if P1,P2 are in between P0,P3 you can't have cusps. (i think it's enough if P1 is "right" of P0 and P2 is left of P3) can you post a few pictures of your problem?